# CSS: How to set 100% width on the first li of ul

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists, css-float

I have a simple UL navigation menu with width of 1000px:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first"><a href="/">google</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">google</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">google</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, how can I set the first element to fit the entire UL width and push the other list items on the right (all LIs should be on the same line - horisontal menu)?

I know I could `float:left` the first and `float:right` the rest, but this will reverse the order of the right - floated elements.

I need a quick, CSS only solution, working even in IE6.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: To clarify, the first element is a logo, the final result is like the header of 9gag.com except the logo should be on the left and all links to the right.

Comment: What order would you like these to be in ? Say the first li is 1 and the second being 2 the third is 3. So you want them inline in a horizontal menu ?

Comment: Yes. To clarify, the first will be a logo. The final result will be like 9gag.com, but all links except the logo should be on the right.

Comment: If i were you i wouldn't put the logo in there. I would have a div called header which contains the logo and the menu separately. Many ways of doing it though, that just makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logo usually should not be a part of navigation menu. It's more appropriate to mark-up it as header (`H1` on home page, and `H3` on rest pages).

```
<h3><a href="/">MyBrand</a></h3>

<ul>
    <li><a href="/products/">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can use then `float: right` for your `UL` list itself to align menu to the right.

Comment: Just tried that and it worked beautifuly, have no idea why it didn't the first time I tried it though..

Comment: By the way, does wrapping the logo (it is an image) in h1 / h3 have any semantical meaning or..?

Comment: As long as image has correct (equal to graphic text) `alt` text, it should have meaning similar to plain-text content identical to `alt` attribute contents. I personally prefer to use image-replacement techniques for things like logos while having plain text in HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

See this example, i don't know your menu is dynamic, but if you have a 'width' for other's li's, is more easier

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e6SWD/12/

```
.menu {
  margin-left: 84px; /* width others 2 li's */
  width: 1000px
}

.menu li {
  display: inline;
}

.menu li.first {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -84px; /* width others 2 li's */
  width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now with more clarification:

http://jsfiddle.net/6DkVx/2/

```
ul {
  width: 1000px;   
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.first { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; left: 0; 
}
```

​

Comment: That should work, but I'm gonna go with Marat Tanalin's solution. Too bad I cannot accept both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this CSS

```
.menu li
{
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated before separate the logo from the main navigation. Do something like this instead.

```
<div id="header>
<div id="logo">Logo here</div>
<ul><li>Rest of links here</li></ul>
</div>
```

The header div is the wrapping div. You could change this to `<header></header>` if you want to do HTML5 (this will work in all browsers even old ones).
Then set the width of the logo, you can use a link there aswell. And float the ul and logo to the left.